# Read and Save only Checked Radio Button to a "particular column in MYSQL" | PHP & Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Technologies used:

- Server Side: PHP
- DB: MYSQL
- Client Side: Ajax to call PHP
- Client Side: HTML
- Usable on: Phonegap

I have four radio button in a Radio Group in HTML

1. Mother
2. Father
3. Self
4. Others

The 4 columns in my table are:

```
| DBMother | DBFather | DBSelf | DBOthers |
```

If I choose `Mother` Radio button, the value should go and save right under the column `DBMother`, rest of the columns should remain blank.

When I choose Radio Button `Self` in HTML, the value should go and save right under Mysql DB column `DBSelf` and remaining columns should remain blank.

I have tried a few codes available on google, but these are for saving information in one single DB Column.

I think I need codes for PHP for server side and Ajax for Client side.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#submit").click(function(){

        var game=$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

        if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {
          alert("Select any value");
        }
        else {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-check.php",
            data: "game="+game,
            success: function() {
              $("#msg").addClass('bg');
              $("#msg").html("value Entered");
            }
          });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <form method="post" action="">
    Select:<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="game" value="Mother">
    <input type="radio" name="game" value="Father">
    <input type="radio" name="game" value="Self">
    <input type="radio" name="game" value="Others">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your attempted code, we're not here to write it all for you.

Comment: @Barmar I have posted the code below

Comment: Post it in the question. Answers are for solution, not continuations of the question.

Comment: @Barmar the code is pasted in Question..